# UITabBarController Header with Title

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have been trying to hours to implement a simple UITabBarController where each view (or tab) has an active header (or top bar) with the title of the view. Is there a way in Xcode 6.1.x to create a UITabBarController with pages whose title is reflected in the top bar?

As it currently stands, I cannot get the top bar to show. I'd prefer not to drag navigation bars to each view and do this manually. Also UINavigationControllers are not necessary here, as each tabbed view will only need to display a single page.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the values of those simulated metrics fields on a storyboard or nib will not actually have any effect on the UI. It's a design/layout aid.

You will need to embed the view controllers within navigation controllers or drag navigation bars into the views.